# I'm trying to get all duplicate rows using db_select

Tags: database

Before I run db_delete, I'm trying to run db_select to test that I am getting all duplicate rows, based on a specific column value.

```
db_select('node_revision', 'n')
    ->where('n.nid NOT IN SELECT MIN(n.nid)')
    ->groupBy('hash')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll();
```

Basically, delete (select for the test) all rows with the same hash value, except for the first one, is my goal.

I'm basing it on this page:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/01/sql-server-delete-duplicate-records-rows/

But for some reason I get the following error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM node_revision n WHERE (n.nid NOT IN SELECT MIN(nid)) GROUP BY hash' at line 1: SELECT FROM {node_revision} n WHERE (n.nid NOT IN SELECT MIN(nid)) GROUP BY hash; Array ( ) in include()
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is ; array ( ) there?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment your query is:

```
SELECT 
FROM 
{node_revision} n
WHERE  (n.nid NOT IN SELECT MIN(n.nid)) 
GROUP BY hash
```

You need to add some fields...

```
db_select('node_revision', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('vid'))
  ->where('n.nid NOT IN SELECT MIN(n.nid)')
  ->groupBy('hash')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAll();
```

Comment: I don't actually need vid though.

Comment: OK, so pick the column that you _do_ need.

Comment: I'm only trying to cull everything with a duplicate hash value, that has the same nid. Even when I try to grab fields, I'm getting an error.

db_select('node_revision', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid', 'hash'))
  ->where('n.nid NOT IN SELECT MIN(n.nid)')
  ->groupBy('hash')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAll();

Comment: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near &#039;SELECT MIN(n.nid)) 
GROUP BY hash&#039; at line 1: SELECT n.nid AS nid, n.hash AS hash
FROM 
{node_revision} n
WHERE  (n.nid NOT IN SELECT MIN(n.nid)) 
GROUP BY hash; Array
(
)

Comment: 'Cull' would surely involve a `DELETE` query? A `SELECT` has to have fields, by definition. There are a few other things wrong with your query, I don't know what you're trying to accomplish so I can't really help. This is wrong: `(n.nid NOT IN SELECT MIN(n.nid))`, needs to be `(n.nid NOT IN (SELECT MIN(n.nid)))`, and there's no `hash` column in `node_revision`, so you can't group on it. Write the SQL query that gets you the right data **first**, then worry about getting it into Drupal

Comment: This is a select query to test a delete query. I'm going to eventually switch to db_delete.

And a custom module was already written to generate a hash value/hash column.

Comment: Basically, I want to look for duplicate rows in the node_revision table. These duplicate rows are determined by the value in the hash column, which is a new column with a theoretically unique hash. If the hash is not unique, then only one node revision with that hash value should exist.

Comment: Ok, but you still need your SQL statement to be **valid** if you want to run it. Sorry but I can't begin to understand what you mean by _"a custom module was already written to generate a hash value"_. How would that relate to a column in the `node_revision` table in an SQL query exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to generate a valid query, but I'm having a hard time using db_select. I'm just not familiar with the syntax.

Comment: Currently my where is generating this, and I'm still getting errors:

WHERE  (n.nid NOT IN (SELECT MIN(n.nid)) from n)

Comment: The problem's with your SQL syntax though, not your PHP syntax. As I said, get the query working through vanilla MySQL first. _Then_ try it with `db_query()` to make sure the raw SQL works through Drupal, and _then_ convert it to `db_select()`. Much, much easier to do it that way I promise you